Making an Output based on Selected Filters
I'm trying to make a proof-of-concept random name generator. I've exhausted just about everything I could think of, but everything I've tried has not functioned. I'm very new to this, so there's bound to be rookie mistakes I'm sure.
It's designed to be 2 dropdown menus to determine what array to choose. It then should randomly choose a name from that array and return it in an output.


var gendervar, countryvar, finalnameset;
gendervar = 3
countryvar = 3

document.getElementById("male").onclick(gendervar = 1)
document.getElementById("female").onclick(gendervar = 2)
document.getElementById("either-g").onclick(gendervar = 3)
document.getElementById("greek").onclick(countryvar = 1)
document.getElementById("norse").onclick(countryvar = 2)
document.getElementById("either-c").onclick(countryvar = 3)

let greek_m = [exampleoption1];
let greek_f = [exampleoption2];
let norse_m = [exampleoption3];
let norse_f = [exampleoption4];
let graeco = [greek_m, greek_f];
let nordic = [norse_m, norse_f];
let masculine = [greek_m, norse_m];
let feminine = [greek_f, norse_f];
let all_of_it = [graeco, nordic];

function filternames() {
  if ((gendervar == 1)(and)(countryvar == 1))
    finalnameset = greek_m;
  else if ((gendervar == 2)(and)(countryvar == 1))
    finalnameset = greek_f;
  else
    finalnameset = null;
}

function randomnames(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
}

function getfinalname() {
  randomnames(finalnameset);
  let finalname = finalnameset[0];
  document.getElementById("output_name").setAttribute.value = finalname;
}
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Gender</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="male">Male</a>
    <a id="female">Female</a>
    <a id="either-g">IDC</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Origin</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="greek">Greek</a>
    <a id="norse">Norse</a>
    <a id="either-c">IDC</a>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="getfinalname()">SUBMIT</button>
<output id="output_name">Press submit to generate a name!</output>




Check your syntax. JS does not use the and keyword in if conditions and you need to provide a function to onclick, which is a property not a method.

Also not how onclick is used. Get small pieces working at a time before combining or extending them into bigger ones.
